# Compile project in SVN repository is that possible

Tags: svn, acc

i had little experience with svn in the past.

Right now, i am working on svn... I have a svn repository "trunk/testProject" it has a copy of test.c and test.h 
(test.c and test.h are tested and compiled on my local working space, and they are already committed to svn repository".

I am using an "acc" compiler that gonna create a test.o and a shared library. What i want and my problem is : how can I let my compiler recognize the HEAD version in my svn repository, then let the compiler to pick up my HEAD version of test.c and test.h  in the svn repo, --- > then compile them and directly throw the test.o and shared library into a production environment ( a directory for production release) ?  ------ I really have no idea about this part I read the svn book but still no luck.
Since there is some setup /security limitation with our company ... I can't test or try my idea :(   .... so please help me at this point @^@

Could somebody answer my question and also provide me some links / articles for me to learn. 
Thank you so much ~~

Comment: What do you mean by compiling or running something in a repository?

Comment: hi, This is what I mean: ... for example I have a svn repository "/trunk/testProject " and a copy of  "test.c" stored under the "testProject" ..... compiling means: run the C compiler as usual, compile the "test.c" and create the "test.o"; and the "test.o" is also in the repository

Comment: Ok, so you checkout and compile... Am I missing anything?

Comment: Thank you bereal, Yes I agree.... I think i didn't explain it clearly. I edited my post, please give some guides...

Comment: You're looking for a continuous integration or continuous delivery system/process.

Comment: Yes, alroc, I think continuous integration/continuous delivery system/process will describe it.... but how ? if it is possible how can i do that... or if it is not possible why ?    any idea /suggest for me ... anything I am lost here

Comment: Anyone ? ...........

Comment: As @alroc mentioned, that's a job for a CI tool, not for a compiler. There are few CI systems, the most popular of those seems to be [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/). Among other things, It allows triggering builds when the repository is updated, running any kind of compilers or build tools etc.

Comment: @user2632336, describing "how" is outside the scope of a StackOverflow discussion. It's a big topic and really can't be covered adequately here. I suggest you start doing some research on the subject and return with specific questions once you've started experimenting with it.